# How can I find the distance between two points within a triangle if I have the distance between each point and each vertex of the triangle?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, triangulation

Title says it all. It would be useful to extend the question to finding the distance if any of the points is outside of the triangle, but I'm trying to figure out the basic problem first.

Comment: You could construct circles at the vertices of the appropriate radii and compute the triple intersection points to find the coordinates of the points.  You might also be able to use barycentric coordinates.